Rudin's RCA 14.13(Area Theorem)
14.13 Theorem
If $F \in H(U-\{0\}), F$ is one-to-one in $U$, and
$$
F(z)=\frac{1}{z}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \alpha_n z^n \quad(z \in U),
$$
then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n\left|\alpha_n\right|^2 \leq 1
$$
This is usually called the area theorem, for reasons which will become apparent in the proof.
Proof. The choice of $\alpha_0$ is clearly irrelevant. So assume $\alpha_0=0$. Neither the hypothesis nor the conclusion is affected if we replace $F(z)$ by $\lambda F(\lambda z)$ $(|\lambda|=1)$. So we may assume that $\alpha_1$ is real.
Put $U_r=\{z:|z|<r\}, C_r=\{z:|z|=r\}$, and $V_r=\{z: r<|z|<1\}$, for $0<r<1$. Then $F\left(U_r\right)$ is a neighborhood of $\infty$ (by the open mapping theorem, applied to $1 / F)$; the sets $F\left(U_r\right), F\left(C_r\right)$, and $F\left(V_r\right)$ are disjoint, since $F$ is one-to-one. Write
$$
F(z)=\frac{1}{z}+\alpha_1 z+\varphi(z) \quad(z \in U)
$$
$F=u+i v$, and
$$
A=\frac{1}{r}+\alpha_1 r, \quad B=\frac{1}{r}-\alpha_1 r .
$$
For $z=r e^{i \theta}$, we then obtain
$$
u=A \cos \theta+\operatorname{Re} \varphi \quad \text { and } \quad v=-B \sin \theta+\operatorname{Im} \varphi \text {. }
$$
Divide Eqs. (5) by $A$ and $B$, respectively, square, and add:
$$
\frac{u^2}{A^2}+\frac{v^2}{B^2}=1+\frac{2 \cos \theta}{A} \operatorname{Re} \varphi+\left(\frac{\operatorname{Re} \varphi}{A}\right)^2-\frac{2 \sin \theta}{B} \operatorname{Im} \varphi+\left(\frac{\operatorname{Im} \varphi}{B}\right)^2 .
$$
By (3), $\varphi$ has a zero of order at least 2 at the origin. If we keep account of (4), it follows that there exists an $\eta>0$ such that, for all sufficiently small $r$,
$$
\frac{u^2}{A^2}+\frac{v^2}{B^2}<1+\eta r^3 \quad\left(z=r e^{i \theta}\right) .
$$
This says that $F\left(C_r\right)$ is in the interior of the ellipse $E_r$ whose semiaxes are $A \sqrt{1+\eta r^3}$ and $B \sqrt{1+\eta r^3}$, and which therefore bounds an area
$$
\pi A B\left(1+\eta r^3\right)=\pi\left(\frac{1}{r}+\alpha_1 r\right)\left(\frac{1}{r}-\alpha_1 r\right)\left(1+\eta r^3\right) \leq \frac{\pi}{r^2}\left(1+\eta r^3\right) .
$$
Since $F\left(C_r\right)$ is in the interior of $E_r$, we have $E_r \subset F\left(U_r\right)$; hence $F\left(V_r\right)$ is in the interior of $E_r$, so the area of $F\left(V_r\right)$ is no larger than (7). The Cauchy-Riemann equations show that the Jacobian of the mapping $(x, y) \rightarrow(u, v)$ is $\left|F^{\prime}\right|^2$. Theorem 7.26 therefore gives the following result:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\pi}{r^2}\left(1+\eta r^3\right) & \geq \iint_{V_r}\left|F^{\prime}\right|^2 \\
& =\int_r^1 t d t \int_0^{2 \pi}\left|-t^{-2} e^{-2 i \theta}+\sum_1^{\infty} n \alpha_n t^{n-1} e^{i(n-1) \theta}\right|^2 d \theta \\
& =2 \pi \int_r^1\left(t^{-3}+\sum_1^{\infty} n^2\left|\alpha_n\right|^2 t^{2 n-1}\right) d t \\
& =\pi\left\{r^{-2}-1+\sum_1^{\infty} n\left|\alpha_n\right|^2\left(1-r^{2 n}\right)\right\}
\end{aligned}
$$
If we divide (8) by $\pi$ and then subtract $r^{-2}$ from each side, we obtain
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N n\left|\alpha_n\right|^2\left(1-r^{2 n}\right) \leq 1+\eta r
$$
for all sufficiently small $r$ and for all positive integers $N$. Let $r \rightarrow 0$ in (9), then let $N \rightarrow \infty$. This gives (2).
My questions:

How can I prove that $F(U_r)$ is a nbhd. of $\infty$ by open mapping theorem?

I have tried to handle the set of zeros and the $F(0)=\infty$(right?) then using the open mapping theorem, and I don't think it is the best way to solve it.

How can I deduce that the inequality holds for sufficiently small $r$ by (4)?


Since $1/F(z)$ hits zero in $U_r$, $F(z)$ hits $\infty$ when in $U_r$. In other words, $\infty\in F(U_r)$. By open mapping theorem, $F(U_r)$ is open, so $F(U_r)$ is a neighborhood of $\infty$.
For the inequality, the argument you presented works for all $r\in(0,1)$, so
$$
\sum_{n=1}^Nn|a_n|^2(1-r^{2n})\le1+\eta r
$$
is valid for all $N\in\mathbb N$ and $r\in(0,1)$. Taking the limit $r\to0^+$ gives
$$
\sum_{n=1}^Nn|a_n|^2\le1
$$
for all $N\in\mathbb N$. Now, just take $N\to+\infty$.
